# Spring boot test, can not load properties file for junit test

Tags: spring-boot, junit

This is my project structure

```
src/main/java
            /main/ApplicationContext.java
src/main/resource/
            /application-context.xml
            /conf/soap.properties
src/test/java
            /main/TestApplicationContext.java           
src/test/resource/
            /application-context-test.xml
            /confTest/soapTest.properties
```

Then `TestApplicationContext.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:application-context-test.xml")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestApplicationContext {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplicationContext.class, args);
  }

}
```

And how I loading properties specific for Junit test

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestApplicationContext.class})
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8081, httpsPort = 443)
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:confTest/soapTest.properties"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

public class ApplicationTest {
    @Test
    void testABC(){
        //test here
    }
}
```

But seem that the properties in `confTest/soapTest.properties` file can not be load in runtime

It show message 
`Could not resolve placeholder 'service.test.url' in value "${service.test.url}"`

In fact  the `service.test.url` is available in `soapTest.properties`

I known this is maybe dupplicate question but I had googled and tried many solutions but not work for me

Are there any wrong with my configuration

Answer (score 0):

@Ryo...use this 
You can use `@TestPropertySource` annotation in your test class.

For example you have this attribute in your mailing.properties file:

```
mailFrom=fromMe@mail.com
```

Just annotate `@TestPropertySource("classpath:config/mailing.properties")` on your test class.

You should be able to read out the property for example with the `@Value` annotation.

```
@Value("${fromMail}")
private String fromMail;
```

To avoid annotate this annotation on multiple test classes you can implement a superclass or meta-annotations.

EDIT1:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:config/mailing.properties")
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private MailService mailService;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    String s = mailService.getMailFrom();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

MailService:

```
@Service
public class MailService {

    @Value("${mailFrom}")
    private String mailFrom;

    public String getMailFrom() {
        return mailFrom;
    }

    public void setMailFrom(String mailFrom) {
        this.mailFrom = mailFrom;
    }
}
```

DemoTestFile:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DemoApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:config/mailing.properties")
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MailService mailService;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        String s = mailService.getMailFrom();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

---

yes @Ryo.... your correct
use this one `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)`

Comment: Thanks, I already using @TestPropertyResource. but it is still not work, I add `order="1"` to `<context:place-holder .../>` then it's work

Comment: @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)

Comment: Hmm, seem another problem happened. after adding `order` attribute, it no longer load config from `/src/main/resources` when i run app without run test